# How can I make task to reuse all of the properties from previous successful run in Spring Cloud DataFlow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm running Spring Cloud Dataflow in Kubernetes and for some reason only part of properties from previous run is reused on the next run.

Here is list of properties on a previous run [image: List of properties on a previous run]

and after I press "Relaunch" it only picks up a couple of properties, but loses URLs and passwords and so on[image: list of properties on the relaunch]

I checked logs of the server and skipper and there's nothing worth seeing. No errors or anything.

Initial free-text properties:

```
app.aquafacts-data-import-fo-fish-farms-biomas.fishfacts.datasource.password=redacted
app.aquafacts-data-import-fo-fish-farms-biomas.fishfacts.datasource.url=redacted
app.aquafacts-data-import-fo-fish-farms-biomas.fishfacts.datasource.username=redacted
app.aquafacts-data-import-fo-fish-farms-biomas.logging.level.com.fishfacts=DEBUG
app.aquafacts-data-import-fo-fish-farms-biomas.spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
app.aquafacts-data-import-fo-fish-farms-biomas.spring.batch.job.enabled=true
```

On the relaunch free-text properties

```
app.aquafacts-data-import-fo-fish-farms-biomas.logging.level.com.fishfacts=DEBUG
app.aquafacts-data-import-fo-fish-farms-biomas.spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
app.aquafacts-data-import-fo-fish-farms-biomas.spring.batch.jdbc.table-prefix=BOOT3_BATCH_
app.aquafacts-data-import-fo-fish-farms-biomas.spring.batch.job.enabled=true
app.aquafacts-data-import-fo-fish-farms-biomas.spring.cloud.deployer.bootVersion=3
app.aquafacts-data-import-fo-fish-farms-biomas.spring.cloud.task.initialize-enabled=false
app.aquafacts-data-import-fo-fish-farms-biomas.spring.cloud.task.schemaTarget=boot3
app.aquafacts-data-import-fo-fish-farms-biomas.spring.cloud.task.tablePrefix=BOOT3_TASK_
```